# TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable when trying to resize image

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to resize my picture, but I keep getting this error: `builtins.TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable`. How would I fix it?

Here is my current code

```
image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.jpg")     #loading image
image = pygame.transform.scale(image(100,100)) #Changing size
screen.blit(image, (500,600))                  #Location of picture
```

Comment: you forgot `,` between `image` and `(100,100)` so it treats `image(100,100)` as  function. Should be `scale(image, (100,100))`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a type. A `,` missing between `iamge` and `(100,100)`:

<s>`image = pygame.transform.scale(image(100,100))`</s>

```py
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (100, 100))
```